# About realm database in android

Tags: realm

I want to use realm database in android ,but I want to create dynamic tables or columns in an existing one.Is it possible with realm database as I wanted to use realm and I am newbie in using the same so don't really understand is it possible or not.

Comment: it is theoretically possible with DynamicRealm but you should generally try to model your data in such a way that it actually fits inside pre-defined tables

Answer (score 0):

To mutate your realm database, you need to use migrations : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations